load a model from checkpoint folder in pyTorch
I am trying to load a model from a certain checkpoint and use it for inference. The checkpoint folder looks like this. How do I load the model in torch from this folder. The resources I could find are for loading from a checkpoint file, not a folder.

import whisper_timestamped as whisper
from transformers import AutoProcessor, WhisperForConditionalGeneration
from peft import prepare_model_for_kbit_training, LoraConfig, PeftModel, LoraModel, LoraConfig, get_peft_model
from peft import PeftModel, PeftConfig
import torch
from datasets import Dataset, Audio
from transformers import AutoFeatureExtractor, WhisperModel

peft_model_id = "aben118/finetuned_model/checkpoint-3900" 

language = "en"
task = "transcribe"
peft_config = PeftConfig.from_pretrained(peft_model_id)
model = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(
    peft_config.base_model_name_or_path, load_in_8bit=False, device_map="auto"
)
model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(model, peft_model_id)
print(model)
model = model.merge_and_unload()
model.save_pretrained(<model_path>)

But it saves it in .safetensors format. I want it to be a model that i can load using torch.load.

Have you tried the safe_serialization flag? Setting to false will prevent the model from being saved as a .safetensors file.
Here's a base example:-
from transformers import AutoModel

model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
model.save_pretrained('./model', safe_serialization=False)
torch.load('./model/pytorch_model.bin')

In your case this would be
model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(model, peft_model_id)
model = model.merge_and_unload()
model.save_pretrained('./model', safe_serialization=False)
torch.load('./model/pytorch_model.bin')

Edit:- Who the HF model class inherits from determines the serializer used when its set to off. torch.load uses pickle to deserialize. The PeftModel uses PreTrainedModel so you should be able to load it in with the above method.



HF Model Parent/Donor Class
.save_pretrained(safe_serialization=?)
serializer
Native Pytorch Deserialisation Support




PretrainedModel
off
pickle
Y


TFPretrainedModel
off
h5
N


FlaxPretrainedModel
off
msgpack
N



save_pretrained()
Peft model donor
